# Lightweight background image hover animation jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background

I am currently using:

```
jQuery('#changeImage').hover(function() 
{ 
    jQuery('body').css("background", "url(img/globo.jpg) center top #1C1C1C fixed"),
    jQuery('body').css("background-size", "cover");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery('body').css("background", "#1C1C1C"); 
});
```

CSS:

```
#image {
background:url("img/image.jpg") fixed top center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

to change a background image on hover.

However, I would like to add some fading animation, in order to make the experience more soft. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

<s>No need to JavaScript here, you can achieve what you're looking for through CSS alone:</s>

```
#image{
    background:url(img/image.jpg) fixed top center;
    background-size:cover;
}
#image:before{
    background:url(img/globo.jpg) center top #1C1C1C fixed
    background-size:cover;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0;
    top:0;
    transition:opacity .5s linear;
    width:100%;
}
#image:hover:before{opacity:1;}
```

Updated following sample link provided in comments:

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery('#changeImage').hover(function(){ 
    jQuery('body').css("background-image", "url(img/globo.jpg)"),
    jQuery('body').addClass("reveal");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery('body').removeClass("reveal"); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color:#1c1c1c;
    background-position:center top;
    background-size:cover;
}
body:before{
    background:#1c1c1c;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    transition:opacity .5s linear;
}
body.reveal:before{
    opacity:0;
}
```

I don't use JQuery so can't fully test this, let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: Hi Shaggy, thanks for your answer, but I didn't manage to solve it. This is the link to the demo I am trying to implement it: http://eatdesignsleep.com/themes/af/black/  - maybe there is somenthing wrong elsewhere. Thanks for your support

Comment: Thanks for the example, @George, I can better see what you're trying to achieve now. I'll update my post above with a better solution momentarily.